# MSACCESS Add records to table from form txt and cbo boxes

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to speed up the process of adding identical stock items to a sales table.  The data is identical for each record to be added.  I have an unbound form with seven fields.  BookID, Purchase Date (date), Item size (text), description (text), Seller Name (text), Condition (text), and Price Paid (Currency).  There is an 8th field that has a number representing the number of records to be added, i.e. 50, meaning 50 stock items to be added.

I've been trying to do this with an append query.  I have a cmd button on the form that runs the append query.

I've added only two fields to the append query at the moment.  When I run the query it adds two records instead of one!  Why?  And I haven't tried adding the date yet - dates are usually a problem!

I was doing it this way based on another question I read on stackoverlow, but don't think this will work the way I need it to. Ultimately, when I click the button, I want it to add the number of records, for example 50, if that is the number in the 8th field.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?  Below is the sql from the append query using the first two fields.

Thanks

```
INSERT INTO tblSale (BookID, BookCoverType)
SELECT tblSale.BookID,
       tblSale.BookCoverType
FROM tblSale
WHERE tblSale.BookID = [forms]![FrmAddKawekaStock]![txtBookID] AND
      tblSale.BookCoverType) = [forms]![FrmAddKawekaStock]![cboKaweka]
```

The final result is shown below.

```
    Private Sub cmdAddStockver2_Click()
    On Error GoTo errorhandler

    Dim sql As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim intx As Integer
    Dim intz As Integer

    intz = Forms!frmaddkawekastock!txtQuantityToAdd

    sql = "tblSale"

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

    MsgBox " adding the record to rs"

    For intx = 1 To intz
    With rs
        .AddNew
        .Fields!BookID = Forms!frmaddkawekastock!txtBookID
        .Fields!bookPurchaseDate = Forms!frmaddkawekastock!txtPurchaseDate
        .Fields![Book Size] = Forms!frmaddkawekastock!cboSize
        .Fields!BookCoverType = Forms!frmaddkawekastock!cboKaweka
        .Fields!Seller = Forms!frmaddkawekastock!cboSellerName
        .Fields!BookCondition = Forms!frmaddkawekastock!txtCondition
        .Fields!BookPaid = Forms!frmaddkawekastock!txtPaidPrice
        .Update
    End With
    MsgBox "Loop done and record added, next loop"
    Next intx

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    MsgBox "Completed sucessfully"

    ExitSub:
        Exit Sub

    errorhandler:
        MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        Resume ExitSub

    End Sub
```

Comment: You should add all data in one `UPDATE` statement.  The reason you are getting more than one record is because the `SELECT` returns more than one record.  Try to restrict it if you really expect a single record to be inserted.

Comment: If I understand right, in order to add a sale of 50 count of an item to your sales table, you actually add 50 individual records, instead of one record with quantity 50. Is that correct?

Comment: Why add so many records?

Comment: Hi Sunknight0.  Yes, 50 individual records.  All exactly the same.  Thanks.

Comment: I decided to drop the initial attempt (using an append query) and move to a recordset. I've managed to get this working pretty much the way I want it to work. I'm not a developer, I've just been copying code from here and there on the internet. If anyone sees anything wrong with what I've ended up with please let me know. The msgbox's are just my way of slowing things down, so if/when an error occurred during my testing, I'd have an idea where the problem was.

Comment: Using DAO (`RecordSet.AddNew`) is actually the best way to do this - no problems with date or string formatting, better performance than running an INSERT query 50 times. -- For debugging, instead of MsgBox you can use `Debug.Print` (Ctrl+G shows the output).

Answer (score 0):

Just answering this to close it.  The recordset code above is what I ended up with.  cheers